# Do I Need to Normalize Data and Compensate for Apparent Overdispersion in Funnel Plots Generated from a 1.2 Million Record Dataset?

Tags: dataset, skewness, overdispersion, funnel-plot

I have an anonymized dataset with 1.2 million dog and cat surgical sterilization records from 81 clinics.  I would like to measure inter-clinic variation in mortality rate as part of a preliminary study that would help justify a second study to survey the clinics in an attempt to find reasons for any detected special cause variation.

At first pass funnel plots seem to be a nice way to visualize the data as the number of surgical cases per clinic varies greatly (between 16 and 80,000 cases). These data are not normally distributed (extreme right skew), and I am additionally concerned that the size of the dataset may lead to apparent over dispersion.

I am using the spreadsheet from the Public Health Observatories http://www.apho.org.uk/resource/item.aspx?RID=47240 to generate the funnel plot.

The non-normalized mortality data looks much like I expect (nearly all clinics within bounds, a few above and a few below), but I wonder if that's two wrongs (non-normal data and uncompensated apparent overdispersion) making a right?  When I normalize the data via square root transform (partial normalization) or logarithmic transformation (better normalization but must drop clinics with 0 deaths) the control limits are much tighter and the majority of clinics are outside of the control limits.  I am concerned that I may need to change the method for calculating the limits.

[image: Normalized and Non-Normalized Funnel Plots]

Comment: Please be aware that to most people what you are doing is *transforming* the data; "normalization" is something entirely different.  There obviously are problems with your transformations, since you cannot even deal with the zeros.  What motivates you to try these particular transformations and what evidence do you have that they accomplish anything useful?

Comment: I think people who use funnel plots in meta-analysis would transform the measure you have on the x-axis rather than the y. A square root transformation might be tried.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and I apologize for imprecise language.  @whuber I transformed the data because the mortality rate was not normally distributed, and I was concerned that this would affect appropriate calculation of the control limits.

Comment: @mdewey I'm not sure if the funnel plots for meta-analysis are the same as for process control [link](http://icvts.oxfordjournals.org/content/9/3/494.full)